# Unable to inspect elements of page which loads only for 1 to 2 sec

Tags: selenium, appium, android-uiautomator

My test case is to automate an application where orders will be generated. But the problem here is once the order is submitted a page will be loaded saying order no bla bla is generated. But this page loads max for 2 sec and it goes to next page. How to get the order number from this page.

Comment: Maybe try and catch the exact page you're talking about using an inspector?

Comment: Did u try locating order id in Firefox

Comment: This does not answer your question, but what use is a page to the user if it disappears so quickly? Doesn't seem like the right place to be providing information (and then checking it). As QA it's sometimes our role to question design as opposed to making do with everything handed to us.

Comment: Back to your subject, are you having trouble locating the element ID to code your automation or is your executing code too slow to grab the text at runtime?

Answer (score 0):

- Open the dev tool before performing the action that causes the desired window to appear.
- Go to the `Sources` tab
- Now perform the action that makes the window to appear.
- When the window is visible press `F8` or `Ctrl + \` on the keyboard to pause script execution.
- Now press `Ctrl + Shift + C` or select the `Select element for inspection` tool from the top left corner of the dev tool.
- Now select the window and get the DOM for the window that hides very fast.